# JQ array with links and AJAX issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays

I'm trying to pass multiple links from array to AJAX. I'm getting links from:

```
var additionalProducts = new Array;

    $(".chk").click(function() {
        additionalProducts=[];
        $('.chk:checked').each(function() {
            additionalProducts.push($(this).attr('data-carturl',$("a[data-slot='"+newslot2[i]+"']").attr('href')));
        });
        var ilosc = additionalProducts.length;

        console.log(additionalProducts);
        console.log(ilosc);
    });
```

I'm getting correct links as I can display it using console log. Can I submit those links using AJAX before I will submit my form ?

//////////// UPDATE

that's my submit function:

```
$('.submitOrder').click(function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    additionalProducts=[];
    $('.chk:checked').each(function() {

        additionalProducts.push($(this).attr('data-carturl',$("a[data-slot='"+newslot2[i]+"']").attr('href')));
    });

        for(var i = 0; i < additionalProducts.length; i++)
            {
                var page = additionalProducts[i];
                $.ajax({
                    url: page,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        console.log(page)
                       },
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(page)
                    }

                });

            }
        window.location = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/my/cart';

});
```

I can get to my cart but still there's no products. console.log(page) works fine for me

```
$("#submitOrder").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();     
        var radio1 = $("input:radio[name=radio1]:checked").attr("data-carturl");

        additionalProducts=[];
        $('.chk:checked').each(function() {

            additionalProducts.push($(this).attr('data-carturl',$("a[data-slot='"+newslot2[i]+"']").attr('href')));
        });

             $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: radio1,
                    data: { theArray: JSON.stringify(additionalProducts ) }

              }),

            $(this).submit();


window.location = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/my/cart';          
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, pass the `data` as a JSON string when using your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'yourwebservice.php'
    data: { theArray: JSON.stringify(additionalProducts ) }
});
```

In the [submit event](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) of the form, prevent the submit until the ajax call is complete:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

And submit it once the ajax call is complete:

```
$(this).submit();
```

If you are using PHP, you can get the array using `$theArray = $_GET['theArray'];`. If you are using ASP.NET: `string json = HttpContext.Current.Request.Querystring['theArray'];`

Comment: @maky Use the submit() event, not click(). Also, you aren't posting any data to the ajax method. In other words, you haven't done anything of what I said here...

Comment: I made all changes and can't submit that form...  can you see any errors ? I'm using radio1 as a link in my ajax call + links form array, thanks for your help!

Comment: @maky Ok, what do you mean by "can't submit the form"? If you want to submit the form after the ajax call is complete, you need to do it in the `success` handler.

Comment: i thing there is some logic issue in that code... i was trying with success handler too. I get to the stage when i can add 3 links (prd.) to my cart (and i should get 4). It's confusing as i need to use one link (radio1) and links from array (up to 3).